# Strange things are happening with my custom jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, logic

I'm setting up a very simple jQuery slider that will fade through 3 paragraphs of text when an arrow (right or left) is clicked. The problem I'm having is that cycling through the paragraphs, it isn't incrementing correctly. On the first arrow click, it skips to the third paragraph. Then repeats the third paragraph after another click.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0h2qy0z/

The basic HTML is:

```
<div class="textSlider">
    <div class="sliderArrow arrowLeft"><span><</span></div>

    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>

    <div class="sliderArrow arrowRight"><span>></span></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery stores the content of each paragraph in an array

```
var paragraphs = [];

$('p', '.textSlider').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    paragraphs.push(content)
});
```

and hides all paragraphs but the first

```
$('p', '.textSlider').first().siblings('p').hide();
```

I've tried to give good comments in the jsfiddle, so that's probably the best way to see what's going on, but it seems like the problem is likely in this bit of code, but I can't seem to figure out what's going on:

```
if (currentParagraph < numParagraphs && currentParagraph >= 0) {
     currentParagraph += direction;   
} else if (currentParagraph < 0) {
    currentParagraph = numParagraphs;
} else {
    currentParagraph = 0;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind, but I changed a few things (simpler to understand, in my opinion):

**HTML:**

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th id="backward"><span><<</span></th>
        <td class="slide-head">Paragraph 1</td>
        <td class="slide-head hidden">Paragraph 2</td>
        <td class="slide-head hidden">Paragraph 3</td>
        <!-- ... -->
        <th id="forward"><span>>></span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="content" align="center">Paragraph 1 content</p>
<div class="paragraphs hidden">Paragraph 1 content</div>
<div class="paragraphs hidden">Paragraph 2 content</div>
<div class="paragraphs hidden">Paragraph 3 content</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}

table td {
    padding:0px 80px 0px 80px;
}

#forward span, #backward span {
    background-color:green;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

#forward:hover span, #backward:hover span {
    font-size:17px;
}

#forward:active span, #backward:active span {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    var headers    = (a) => $(".slide-head:eq(" + a + ")"),
        content    = $(".content"),
        paragraphs = (a) => $(".paragraphs:eq(" + a + ")"),
        curIndex   = 0;

    $("#backward, #forward").click(function() {
        headers(curIndex).addClass('hidden');
        if ($(this).attr("id") === "backward") {
            curIndex = (curIndex > 0) ? curIndex - 1 : $('.slide-head').length - 1;
        } else {
            curIndex = (curIndex < $('.slide-head').length - 1) ? curIndex + 1 : 0;
        }
        headers(curIndex).removeClass('hidden');
        content.text(paragraphs(curIndex).text());
    });
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0h2qy0z/16/)**